# Store documentId as field in document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store the documentId created in collection as the field/property as docid in the same document. I am using cloud firestore.

It is showing error "ReferenceError: doc is not defined"
 whenever I try and store the doc.id

```
db.collection("Colleges").doc(user.uid).collection('Internships').doc().set({

          CompanyName :this.I_company,
            InternshipTitle : this.I_title,

            duration: this.duration,
            amount:this.I_amount,
            week:this.week,
            docid: doc.id
})
```

Comment: What error are you receiving when you store the doc id?

Comment: "ReferenceError: doc is not defined"   i am getting this as error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, a call to the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#doc) method of a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) without any path will return a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html) with "an automatically-generated unique ID".

But you have to do as follows: first get the new `DocumentReference`, then use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.html#set) method on this `DocumentReference`.

```
var docRef = db.collection("Colleges").doc(user.uid).collection('Internships').doc();

docRef.set({

          CompanyName :this.I_company,
            InternshipTitle : this.I_title,

            duration: this.duration,
            amount:this.I_amount,
            week:this.week,
            docid: docRef.id
})
```

---

However, you may double check if you really need to write the `docRef.id` in a specific field of the document, because in any case you can get it later with the [`id`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#id) property.